# how to get current wifi connection info in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to find if `scanResult` is the currently connected wifi network.

here is my code

```
public boolean IsCurrentConnectedWifi(ScanResult scanResult) 
{
    WifiManager mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo currentWifi = mainWifi.getConnectionInfo();
    if(currentWifi != null)
    {
        if(currentWifi.getSSID() != null) 
        {
            if(currentWifi.getSSID() == scanResult.SSID)
            return true;
        }
    }  
    return false;
}
```

I have no problem with getting scanresult.

I'm always getting the currentWifi null.

Where am I doing wrong or is there any alternative method to do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Most probably you have already found answer: `currentWifi.getSSID()` is quoted in most cases where `scanResult.SSID` is not (and of course you must not use `==` on strings :)).

Try something like this, it returns current `SSID` or `null`:

```
public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
  String ssid = null;
  ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (connectionInfo != null && !StringUtil.isBlank(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
      ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
    }
  }
  return ssid;
}
```

also permissions are required:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

`StringUtil` is not a standard Android class, so you can use `TextUtils` instead. The code then looks like this:

```
public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
  String ssid = null;
  ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
      ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
    }
  }
  return ssid;
}
```

Comment: as of now `connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);`is officially deprecated. so sad.

Comment: `getNetworkInfo` is deprecated, use `getActiveNetworkInfo` with `networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI`

Comment: Please note that with latest Android versions you also need location permissions of some kind to actually get the SSID

Answer (score 20):

My (used to be) non-deprecated, modified approach to the current answer

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()

```
public static String getCurrentSsid(Context context) {
        String ssid = null;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (connectionInfo != null && !StringUtil.isBlank(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
                ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
            }
        }

    return ssid;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` instead of `StringUtil.isBlank()`

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: when i run this code its just return `02:00:00:00:00:00` that it ! :|

Comment: Well, now it's deprecated. (Deprecated since API 29)

Answer (score 6):

**Update Android Oreo.
You will also need to add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION Permission in Manifest otherwise it will return unknown SSID**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


 fun getCurrentSsid(context: Context): String {
            var ssid = "NA"
            val connManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            if (networkInfo.isConnected) {
                val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                val connectionInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
                if (connectionInfo != null && !connectionInfo.ssid.isEmpty()) {
                    ssid = connectionInfo.ssid
                }
            }
            return ssid
        }
```

Comment: when i run this code its just return `02:00:00:00:00:00` that it ! :|