# Know when wifi is connected to a particular SSID

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing an app in which I need to start a service when the WiFi is connected to a predefined SSID. Can anyone help me with this? Is there a broadcast in android that is fired when WiFi is connected (not turned on) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its called [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

You can use *getType()* to check whether it is a WiFi connection:

```
netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362314/wifi-connect-disconnect-listener) for more information.

**EDIT**

To obtain the SSID try:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.getSSID();
```

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811315/how-to-get-current-wifi-connection-info-in-android)

Comment: And how would i check for the SSID it is connected to?

Comment: I have edited the post since I can't figure out howto format comments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a `Broadcast` for this: [NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION). When the new state is CONNECTED, the `Intent` includes the BSSID as an extra (cf. the documentation linked above). You can check the state via the included `NetworkInfo` object.