# Android WiFi Connection Info

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm getting wifi connection info this way:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

But, could `getConnectionInfo` method return `null` in any case? Android documentation reference say this:

> Return dynamic information about the current Wi-Fi connection, if any
>   is active.

I guess if the device is not connected to any network it will return `null`, won't it?

Thanks

Comment: by checking wifi is connected are you also checking if the internet is available or not ?

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811315/how-to-get-current-wifi-connection-info-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will return `null`, if it is not connected to the wi-fi.

But if you are also checking whether internet is available by using above code, then it is not 100% correct way to do so.
Cause it may happen that your device is connected to wifi but no internet is available. so for that 
you have to ping any live site (such as [google](http://www.google.com),[facebook](http://www.facebook.com), or any other trusted  website) and check if the returned status code is 200.

I hope this helps.